C# OfficeOpenXml ExcelPackage. Как получить высоту ячейки?
Есть набор табличных данных, которые я сохраняю в excel-файл.
Каждую ячейку из таблицы данных я помещаю в соответствую ячейку excel. Высота ячейки установлена в "Авто".
Проблема в том, что максимальная высота ячейки в MS excel - 409pt. Если данных больше, чем влезает в ячейку - данные при просмотре обрезаются и не печатаются. В результате пользователь может распечатать документ, в котором отсутствует часть данных.
Программно я могу соединить две ячейки по высоте и тогда максимальная высота ячейки будет 800pt, но на этапе формирования файла я не могу получить информацию о высоте ячейки. Вероятно, высота автоматически подстраивается под содержимое уже после открытия документа в MS excel.
Спрогнозировать высоту ячейки я не могу - в содержимом ячейки присутствует энное количество строк различной длинны(с переносом строк) и с разным оформлением, кроме того, перед формированием документа ширина столбца задается пользователем.
Можно добиться нужного результата, если группировать две строки и тогда общая высота будет 800pt, но это нужно делать выборочно, а определить сколько занимает текст в ячейке я могу лишь приблизительно.
Кусок кода:
sheet.Cells[row, c_col].IsRichText = true;
sheet.Cells[row,c_col].Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Medium, System.Drawing.Color.Black);
sheet.Cells[row, c_col].Style.WrapText = true;
sheet.Cells[row, c_col].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;

string str = column.ValueFor(gridRow).ToString();
ExcelRichTextHtmlUtility.SetRichTextFromHtml(sheet.Cells[row,c_col], str, "", 16);


Вы сами придумали сделать печать с помощью Excel? Может, Word попробовать?

@rotabor теоретически можно и в word , но там тоже может быть не все гладко - количество столбцов тоже переменное. Excel хорошо справляется с переносом и печатью таблиц ячеек, которые не влезли на лист принтера. На счет word я не уверен.

А где ваш код? Когда я работал с excel через com, то можно было узнать о ячейке все и изменять ее.

@OliverPatterson работаю в .net с экселем, приложение на линуксе крутится. Код добавил.

Может этот вопрос будет полезен?
